# install app - push notification alertview callback

Tags: ios, keyboard, push-notification, uialertview, overlap

I'm developing an app the uses push notification.

In method -

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

I call -

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
   (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

to register for push notification. Everything works fine.
But also it install I want to show an `alert view` that has an `UITextField` than needs to "becomeFirstResponder".

The problem is that the keyboard overlaps the enablePushNotofication alertview's buttons and the user can not dismiss it.

[image]

Anyhow, is there a method that is called when the enablePushNotofication alertview is dismissed? (so i can show my alertview then)

Thanks

Comment: @Luke the UIAlertView is triggered by the system, are you sure that it will invoke your own delegate methods without your instance being registered as a delegate? ...just asking cause it seems unlikely to me.

Comment: The enable push notification alertview is a system alert view. the class that calls it will also be it's delegate?

Answer (score 1):

The code to register for remote notifications should be called every time your app launches. In case the user's token changes, so you can update this on your server.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
 (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

With that in mind, since this is being called every time the app launches you'll know whether it succeeds or fails. Place the code for your text field to become first responder after it's already registered for notifications.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
```

Comment: if the user doesn't dismiss the alert with the textfield, this will still happen. right?

Comment: You'll want to display your custom alert after you the push notification registration succeeds or fails. If the user cancels/allows the Push Notif prompt, it will call one of those methods and you can display your own alert.

Comment: If the notification registration is successful (- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken is called), the "enable notifications" alert view is shown. Same problem. But solved this by registerring for push notification after the user dismisses the alert with the textfield.